# python and selenium: Repeat a line of code until it reaches end of page...once it can't go to next listing... click next page

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

This is the last part of code I am trying to work with...

Basically, I want it to repeat the for listing in all listings until it gets to the end of the page. Currently there are about 23 listings on the page... right now this is simply clicking each listing until it reaches the end.... My goal is to keep this code repeating until it reaches end of page then goes to next page.. any help is appreciated.

```py
time.sleep(3)
all_listings = driver.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value = "/html/body/div[5]/div[3]/div[4]/div/div/main/div/section[1]/div/ul/li")
for i in range(2):
    for listing in all_listings:
        print("test")
        listing.click()
        time.sleep(5)
```

Now for the next page the element is this:

```html
<button aria-label="Page 2" type="button" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-627="627">
  <span>2</span>
</button>
```

How can I make it so it does the code, then does (page +1) or something so it goes:

- page1...
- clicks through all listings...
- then gets attribute and clicks Page 2... and so on

```py
time.sleep(3)
all_listings = driver.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value = "/html/body/div[5]/div[3]/div[4]/div/div/main/div/section[1]/div/ul/li")
for i in range(2):
    for listing in all_listings:
        print("test")
        listing.click()
        time.sleep(5)
```

Then once it gets to end it throws error (because it can't find next element).

Comment: Well seems like your element doesn't exist then or has a differend identifier. Please provide at least the relevant HTML or the url to the website.

Comment: essentially I'm trying to apply for jobs automatically using LinkedIn... I have it do everything up to the point where it shows every job on the current page. if you use the For listing code like i have it will work until it gets to the bottom of the page... then it stops because it cant keep repeating